# This application cannot tree shake icons fonts

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, flutter-dependencies

While trying to build my app in release mode I encountered the following the compiler error:
"This application cannot tree shake icons fonts."

terminal logs:

```
flutter build ios --release  
Building com.xxx.xxx for device (ios-release)...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: C7T4CHU88Y
Running Xcode build...                                                  
                                                   
Xcode build done.                                           31.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    This application cannot tree shake icons fonts. It has non-constant instances of IconData at the following locations:
      - file:///Users/user-app/lib/screens/categories/subcategories.dart:830:35
      - file:///Users/user-app/lib/screens/home/home.dart:387:17
      - file:///Users/user-app/lib/screens/home/home.dart:399:17
      - file:///Users/user-app/lib/screens/home/home.dart:411:17
      - file:///Users/user-app/lib/screens/home/home.dart:423:17
      - file:///Users/user-app/lib/screens/product/all_products.dart:516:31
      - file:///Users/user-app/lib/screens/tab/saveditems.dart:324:31
      - file:///Users/user-app/lib/screens/tab/searchitem.dart:496:31
```

The error could result from the following file:

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Text(
          MyLocalizations.of(context).goToCart,
          style: textBarlowRegularBlack(),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 4),
        Icon(
          IconData(
            0xe911,
            fontFamily: 'icomoon',
          ),
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: this solve my problem [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76375385/13377344)

Answer (score 71):

Try build with `--no-tree-shake-icons` command.

Comment: Can someone tell me where I can set this in Xcode please? Thanks.

Comment: for further explanation about this please refer to
https://github.com/Ahmadre/FlutterIconPicker/issues/9#issuecomment-664844488

Comment: @NickWright flutter build ios --no-tree-shake-icons
in terminal

Comment: @anson when I do this, none of the material icons I have used show up - do you know why this could be?

Comment: added this one in Codemagic build arguments and works. :D

Comment: I just tested. With --no-tree-shake-icons my web app is 8 Mb, without its 25 Mb. Thats three times the size. This should be made very clear in the answer.

Comment: @最白目 Did you test wrong? Supposedly --no-tree-shake-icons will make the application bigger

Comment: @Septian Dika You´re absolutely correct. I mixed up the two values. The application is 3 times bigger when using --no-tree-shake-icons. That was also my point. This answer should warn about this.

Answer (score 17):

Add a "const" before the IconData.

```dart
Icon(
  const IconData(
    0xe911,
    fontFamily: 'icomoon',
  ),
  color: Colors.black,
),
```

Comment: What about when using Icon.myicon?

Answer (score 14):

For `run`

```
flutter run --release --no-tree-shake-icons
```

For **Android** build

```
flutter build apk --release --no-tree-shake-icons
```

For **iOS** build

```
flutter build ipa --release --no-tree-shake-icons
```

Comment: Is it possible to add those extra arguments permanently somewhere instead of manually running these ?

Answer (score 3):

For flutter you can export apk with this

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi --no-tree-shake-icons
```

Answer (score -3):

For me also facing same issue in latest version of flutter. So as of now I've downgraded to Channel stable v1.17.5 to skip this tree-shake-icons issue.

Comment: It's not a reliable solution. You can disable the tree shake as indicated by other answers.