# why the xcode build parameter --no-tree-shake-icons did not work

Tags: xcode, flutter

I am using xcode(`v13.4.1`) to build a flutter app, when I first build the app, shows error like this:

```
This application cannot tree shake icons fonts. It has non-constant instances of IconData at the following locations:
```

and I found the answer from [This application cannot tree shake icons fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63335694/this-application-cannot-tree-shake-icons-fonts). and add some parameter in xcode like this:

[image]

but did not work, am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to set a flag within the `User-defined` variables in Xcode in order to disable tree shaking icons.

1. Select the top most `Runner` in the left pane.
2. Press `Build Settings` and scroll all the way down.
3. Add `TREE_SHAKE_ICONS` with a value of `false` as in the image below.

[image]

I hope this helps!